Going directly into my how can i remove the <li> element from the normal document flow when hovered over it without moving it away from its position?
I want to make the text in the li element to move out of the document flow and increase its z-index so that increasing the size of the text does not affect the position and structure of the other elements.


nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 2rem 10px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 5vw;
}

nav div ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

nav div ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.2rem;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav div ul li:hover {
  position: absolute;
}

@media(max-width:500px) {
  nav {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
}
<nav>
  <h3>Writings</h3>
  <div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li>Categories</li>
      <li>Articles</li>
      <li>About</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>



I have tried position:relative in the ul and position:fixed/absolute in the li on hover but it does not give the required result. The text moves to the side when i want it to stay at its original position and come on top of all the other elements if required.

Scale? Perhaps.

You can transform with a scale on hover as that does not affect neighboring elements' positions.
This snippet adds a little transition time to it also, and a background of white so if the text is a little too big and overlaps a neighbor it is clearly seen.


nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 2rem 10px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 5vw;
}

nav div ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

nav div ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.2rem;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.3s linear;
}

nav div ul li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  background: white;
}

@media(max-width:500px) {
  nav {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
}
<nav>
  <h3>Writings</h3>
  <div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li>Categories</li>
      <li>Articles</li>
      <li>About</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>



